# Back to Back Single Entry Visas

Tags: visas, schengen

I got a single entry Schengen visa C type from my Qatar to Italy for 10 days validity on next November and now I have to visit France after those 10 days directly, so is it normal to apply for another visa to France and have back to back two visas one from 02-11 till 11-11 and another one from 11-11 to 17-11?

Also is there any effect of having both as a single entry?